# Print sorted integer array element

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, mfc

I'm trying to find the max and min values of an array. I have 'numArray', which is a string of comma separated numbers (e.g. - 3,5,1,6). I'm using a tokenizer to break them into individual ints and storing them in a separate array. I'm then sorting them and printing the 0th element, however 'nums[0]' prints the whole array in the exact order, as in 3,5,1,6.
I tried commenting the sorting part but I still got the whole array. What am I doing wrong?
I am a beginner in C++.

```
CString str = numArray;
int i=0;
int nums[50]; 
int nTokenPos = 0;
CString strToken = str.Tokenize(_T(","), nTokenPos);

while (!strToken.IsEmpty())
{
    int x = atoi(strToken);
    nums[i]=x;
    strToken = str.Tokenize(_T(","), nTokenPos);
    i++;
}
std::sort(nums,nums+50);
int min = nums[0];
CString someStr;
someStr.Format(_T("The minimum number is: %d"), min);
minMaxAvg.SetWindowTextA(str);
```

Comment: Pass `someStr` instead of `str`.

Comment: You sort the complete Array and not only the part with numbers. Remember that the Array isn't initialized and contains garbage!
std::sort(nums,nums+i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error lies in the fact that your argument to `minMaxAvg.SetWindowTextA` is `str` when you probably meant to pass `someStr`, ie. you are passing the original string instead of your newly formatted one.

```
minMaxAvg.SetWindowTextA(str);     /* <- this           */
minMaxAvg.SetWindowTextA(someStr); /* <- should be this */
```